# How do I create a CSR from Salesforce containing an ORG element?

Tags: certificates

I am trying to create a new certificate in Salesforce. I have filled in the fields in the certificate record, exported a CSR and get the following error message from the CA (Network Solutions)

> CSR Validation Errors:
>
> Org Name can not be null or empty string.

The current certificate looks like this: CN=theportal.thecompany.org, OU=nsProtect Secure Xpress, OU=Domain Control Validated
Expiration: 20 Aug 2020 23:59:59 GMT

What can I do to put a valid value for ORG Name in the CSR?

Edited: After looking at wikipedia, I realized that there is no "ORG=" element in the cert.  "O=" is what needs to be filled in.  Filling in "Company" in the certificate record will do that.

It's not clear how previous certificates were obtained without "O=" being filled in.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to generate the CSR using the Certificate and Key edit screen to generate a new signing request for the Certificate Authority. The company legal name is a mandatory field on it, so will prevent the CSR getting generated without it. The legal name will be the registered corporate entity for the company, so if you were generating one for MyCompany Ltd registered in the UK you would need to enter

- Common Name: mycompany.co.uk
- Company: MyCompany Ltd
- Department: IT
- State/Province: London
- City: London
- Country: UK

Full details at the [SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&type=5)

[image]